# How to make Collision detection last for a Time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, collision-detection

So, i have some kinda of a special situation with collision.
i need to give an Example to deliver my point so please hear me out!
in my game i have the main player who runs on different spots, each spot has it's own button on the screen!
what i want to do is : when the player is on the spot, if the button was pressed while it still touching the spot then you pass!
if the button wasn't pressed you lose.
i have made all of this and it's fine!,
but my problem is that my collision detect the first pixel of collision only! so if you pressed the button while being on the middle of the spot or the end of it, it won't work!
i know it might be simple but please i need help!!
my Collision method :

```
 public boolean collision(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    if(Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(), b.getRectangle()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

 if(collision(helobaby.get(i), player))
            {
                helobaby.remove(i);
                enemykilled.add(new Death(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.
                        helobabyultimate), player.width + 125, 210, 220, 180, player.getScore(), 12));

                if(bbypressed) {

                    missiles.remove(i);

                    killed.add(new Death(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.
                            babykilled), player.width + 155, 130, 233, 233, player.getScore(), 5));

                    killed.add(new Death(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.
                            rebaby), player.width + 100, 250, 233, 233, player.getScore(), 14));

                    killed.get(i).getAnimation().setDelay(50);
                }
                break;
            }
```

if you need anymore info just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
a.getRectangle().overlaps(b.getRectangle);
```

If you do this, it will be checking if the rectangle of "a" overlaps the rectangle of "b", in his total area, not the x and the y pixel only

(Sorry about my english)

Comment: Are you sure the code is right! because i'm getting an error on `overlaps`